# How to display information from Two sql tables on my blog using php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to display information from my SQL tables on my web blog. I have two tables blog_posts and blog_members which look like

```
Blog_members
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| memberID | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
 blog_posts
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| postID    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| postTitle | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDesc  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postCont  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDate  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am able to add the information from one table but I want to display memeberID when I post an article do I need additional columns in the blog_posts table if so how would I go about this would I need to use a join?

I am displaying the information on my blog using the PHP below.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
            // $stmt = $db->query('SELECT memberID FROM blog_members');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                echo '<div>';
                    echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                    echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                    // echo '<p> by'.$row['memberID'].'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                    echo '<p1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p1>';             
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<hr />';
```

that displays the posts but not the memberID I would like a post to have the member that created it aswell.

Comment: You should have `memberID ` in the `blog_posts` table, so you can connect them.

Comment: The answer to both of your question is: yes!

Comment: Is there any additional table that is mapping both entities (members and posts)?

Comment: there is no additional table, would I require one?

Answer (score 0):

Think about a row in your posts table. How do you know which member that row belongs to? As mentioned in the comments, you can add a `memberId` to your posts table so that you can join the two tables and find both the member that belongs to a post, as well as the posts for a particular member. One convention for these columns is to prefix them with something like `fk` (foreign key) to indicate their role on the table. The table might look like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| postID      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| postTitle   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDesc    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postCont    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDate    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fkMemberID  | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then after you have retrieved a post, you will have the memberId that is the owner of that post, and you can retrieve the member details using that id.

(You would also create a separate foreign key object in the database which maintains the integrity of the foreign key columns. i.e. it makes sure you don't put a memberId of say 53 into the posts table fkMemberId column unless there is a memberId of 53 in the member table. You probably already know that but just thought to mention. :) )